# Publish (or upgrade) a netcoreapp2.0 / ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an old solution I have inherited and have limited experience in this area. It is a web app that uses the `TargetFramework = netcoreapp2.0` and ASP.NET Core 2.0 package.

I realize this is old and I believe is no long supported, but it works for our use case and we use it once a year for about 3 days.  Previously I believe it was published to some old (free?) Azure service or something that seems to be shut down now. And seems like Azure only supports .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 and .NET 6 & 7

Questions:

- Can I still publish a web app using ASP.NET Core 2.0 to somewhere?
- Is there any relatively easy update path to go from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to something that is supported?

Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: it's really out of support now and could you pls check if [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9149) helped you?

Comment: Update - Upgraded the code to netcoreapp3.1, which was mainly a few reference changes and minimal code changes, the hosting provider supports this version of netcore.